# What KB means in 38NiCrMo4 (KB)?

Tags: steel, material-science, alloys

I've been dealing with an engineering drawing that has a material called 38nicrmo4(kb) in Italian UNI standard. It appears that it is equivalent of 36crnimo4 in DIN or commercially named VCN100.
In the drawing "kb" part is absent and it has had me wondering and searching about it.
What does kb mean?

Comment: something they use in Italy.  https://www.mitsubishicarbide.net/contents/mmus/enus/manual/material_cross_reference.pdf

Comment: I've seen this table. Question is that What does kb mean?